# Create a directory in WordPress Multisite subsite directory

Tags: php, wordpress, copy, mkdir

I am attempting to create a directory in a WordPress Multisite subsite directory.

The subsite directory is located at `/home/site/site.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/site_id/` where site_id is the actual id# of the subsite.

I'm looking to create a directory under the site_id directory, and then add a file to that directory from elsewhere in my network.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// Get current site id
global $current_blog;
$shop_id = $current_blog->blog_id;    
// Create directory for current site if does not exist

if (!file_exists(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/sites/' . $shop_id . '/new-directory/')) {
    mkdir(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/sites/' . $shop_id . '/new-directory/', 0777, true);
}
//Copy download.php to new directory
$download_file = 'https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/new-directory/download.php';
$copy_download = 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/' . $shop_id . '/new-directory/download.php';
if (!file_exists('https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/' . $shop_id . '/new-directory/download.php')) {
    copy($download_file, $copy_download);
}
```

When I run this, I get a failed to open stream: No such file or directory on line 30. Line 30 is the `copy($download_file, $copy_download);` line.

Comment: Try removing `https://example.com`. I think `copy` mostly only works on local files. See the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: The example.com bit worked. I replaced `https://example.com/wp-content` with `WP_CONTENT_DIR`  and life is good! Thanks!

Comment: great, glad to hear it and you're welcome. Would you like me to post that as an answer? You don't have to, it's your choice. I was also going to suggest using `WP_CONTENT_DIR` in its place.

Comment: I'd be glad to accept it as the answer. I love when it's a simple fix!!

Comment: Done. Yeah, those easy ones always brighten's up one's day, *cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per OP's request to close the question.

Remove `https://example.com`.

- `https://example.com/wp-content` actually, being a "joint venture".

`copy` mostly only works on local files.

- Consult the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Plus, as I did think it (*but didn't actually say it*), to replace that with `WP_CONTENT_DIR` in its place.